# Click a radio button with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to select a radio button using Python Selenimum. I have already tried all solutions posted yet nothing is working for the given website. My full code is:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

baseDomain = "https://www.budgetdirect.com.au"
startUrl = baseDomain + "/start/home.html"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["ignore-certificate-   errors"])
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
browser.get(startUrl)
#Selects the start date
el = browser.find_element_by_id('service_response_policy_policyBase_commencementDate')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == '28/07/2015':
        option.click()

#Selects the insurance type
el = browser.find_element_by_id('service_response_home_other_summarisedCoverType')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'Home':
        option.click()
time.sleep(1)

#Inserts Post code
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_id("service_response_icAddress_postCode")
inputElement.send_keys('2000')
time.sleep(1)
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) # simulates selecting the enter key

#inserts street address
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_id("service_response_icAddress_streetSearch")
inputElement.send_keys('161 Kent Street')
time.sleep(1)
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.TAB) # simulates selecting the enter key
#inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(1)

#Selects the ownership status
el = browser.find_element_by_id('service_response_home_occupancy_ownership_residenceOccupancyStatus')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'Owner Occupied':
        option.click()
time.sleep(1)

#Selects the year of moving in
el = browser.find_element_by_id('service_response_home_occupancy_ownership_yearMovedIn')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'More than 5 years':
        option.click()
time.sleep(1)

#Selects the home type
el = browser.find_element_by_id('service_response_transactionData_homeType')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'Freestanding Home':
        option.click()

####PROBLEM WITH CODE HERE####

#Ticks no to body corporate
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//input[@type="radio" and @value="N"]')[0].click # Unsuccessful to select
browser.find_element_by_id('service_response_home_homeFeatures_bodyCorporateStrataTitle_N').click() # Unsuccessful to select

for i in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@type="radio"]'): # Unsuccessful to select
    try:
        i.click()
    except:
        pass
###############################
```

The code works fine until it has to select the radio button. As illustrated, I have tried several methods to select the radio button but nothing appears to work. Any ideas welcome!

Comment: it's invisible. You can NOT click an element which is invisible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generic/robust xpath:-

```
el = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='service_response_home_homeFeatures_bodyCorporateStrataTitle_N']");
el.click();
```

Comment: Have tried, but without success. Do you know another solution? I'm trying to click in a radio button in surveymonkey form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
el = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='panel-2-body']/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/label[2]")
el.click()
```